# Alternative for std::set without memory reallocation?

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, stl, set

In an application i generate a lot of subproblems exhaustively and solve them using "std::set" operations. For this I need to "*insert*" and "*find*" elements and also "*iterate*" over the sorted list.

The problem is that for each of the millions of subproblems the "std::set" implementation allocates new memory each time I insert an element in the set which makes the whole application very slow:

```
{   // allocate a non-value node
    _Nodeptr _Pnode = this->_Getal().allocate(1); // <- bottleneck of the program
```

Is there some stl-structure that allows me to to the above operations in "O(log(n))" while not reallocating any memory?

Comment: [Unordered_set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set)?

Comment: @Basilevs in an *unordered* set I can't iterate over the sorted list :-)

Comment: Do inserts happen often?

Comment: @Basilevs yes, very very often. That is the problem.

Comment: If you know the number of insertions in advance a `boost::flat_set` might help you.

Comment: @pmr, even with move semantics insert will take O(n)

Comment: [Bitset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)?

Comment: @Basilevs I don't know the size of the set at compile-time.

Comment: Sorted deque, no more options.

Comment: @moooeeeep yes, all operations mentioned happen very often, but I only need to iterate over a small part of the list.

Comment: "I don't know the size of the set at compile-time." - yet you don't want reallocation.. how's that going to work? oO

Comment: @KarolyHorvath When I generate the problem I will know the size of the set (depends on user input), but not at compile-time.

Comment: Did you try using a custom allocator which allocates from a pool instead of using the general purpose allocator? I'd actually be quite interested to see if that works but with the problem statement I have no way to verify if using an allocator makes any difference.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Thank you, I didn't know this was possible but I think it will work.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: That was the 1st comment...

Comment: What's the order of operations? Are the insert and find operations intertwined, or do all the insert operations happen first? Do you only iterate over the whole set at the end or at any time? Is this for any specific type (and, if numeric values, are the values within some bounds)?

Comment: @Dukeling There is no fixed order, (insert and find operations alternate).

Comment: I agree with the flat_set or a sorted vector.  Forget O(n), the memory allocator is your overhead, and memory isn't random access anyway (due to cache).  Seriously, measure it with a sorted std::vector.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using a custom allocator seems a way to reduce the amount of time spent for building and releasing a `std::set<...>`. Below is a complete demo of a simple allocator together with a program profiling the resulting times.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <memory>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <typename T, std::size_t pool_size = 1024>
class pool_allocator
{
private:
    std::vector<T*> d_pools;
    T*              d_next;
    T*              d_end;
public:
    template <typename O>
    struct rebind {
        typedef pool_allocator<O, pool_size> other;
    };
    pool_allocator(): d_next(), d_end() {}
    ~pool_allocator() {
        std::for_each(this->d_pools.rbegin(), this->d_pools.rend(),
                      [](T* memory){ operator delete(memory); });
    }
    typedef T value_type;
    T*   allocate(std::size_t n) {
        if (std::size_t(this->d_end - this->d_next) < n) {
            if (pool_size < n) {
                // custom allocation for bigger number of objects
                this->d_pools.push_back(static_cast<T*>(operator new(sizeof(T) * n)));
                return this->d_pools.back();
            }
            this->d_pools.push_back(static_cast<T*>(operator new(sizeof(T) * pool_size)));
            this->d_next = this->d_pools.back();
            this->d_end  = this->d_next + pool_size;
        }
        T* rc(this->d_next);
        this->d_next += n;
        return rc;
    }
    void deallocate(T*, std::size_t) {
        // this could try to recycle buffers
    }
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <typename Allocator>
void time(char const* name, std::vector<int> const& random) {
    std::cout << "running " << name << std::flush;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    high_resolution_clock::time_point start(high_resolution_clock::now());

    std::size_t size(0);
    {
        std::set<int, std::less<int>, Allocator> values;
        for (int value: random) {
            values.insert(value);
        }
        size = values.size();
    }

    high_resolution_clock::time_point end(high_resolution_clock::now());
    std::cout << ": size=" << size << " time="
              << duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - start).count() << "ms\n";
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    std::cout << "preparing..." << std::flush;
    std::size_t count(10000000);
    std::vector<int> random;
    random.reserve(count);
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(random), count, [](){ return std::rand(); });
    std::cout << "done\n";

    time<std::allocator<int>>("default allocator      ", random);
    time<pool_allocator<int, 32>>("custom allocator (32)  ", random);
    time<pool_allocator<int, 256>>("custom allocator (256) ", random);
    time<pool_allocator<int, 1024>>("custom allocator (1024)", random);
    time<pool_allocator<int, 2048>>("custom allocator (2048)", random);
    time<pool_allocator<int, 4096>>("custom allocator (4096)", random);
    time<std::allocator<int>>("default allocator      ", random);
}

// results from clang/libc++:
// preparing...done
// running default allocator      : size=10000000 time=13927ms
// running custom allocator (32)  : size=10000000 time=9260ms
// running custom allocator (256) : size=10000000 time=9511ms
// running custom allocator (1024): size=10000000 time=9172ms
// running custom allocator (2048): size=10000000 time=9153ms
// running custom allocator (4096): size=10000000 time=9599ms
// running default allocator      : size=10000000 time=13730ms

// results from gcc/libstdc++:
// preparing...done
// running default allocator      : size=10000000 time=15814ms
// running custom allocator (32)  : size=10000000 time=10868ms
// running custom allocator (256) : size=10000000 time=10229ms
// running custom allocator (1024): size=10000000 time=10556ms
// running custom allocator (2048): size=10000000 time=10392ms
// running custom allocator (4096): size=10000000 time=10664ms
// running default allocator      : size=10000000 time=17941ms
```

Comment: There is something going on, though: when using a pool size of 1, the `pool_allocator` actually has to do more work, at least for the allocation, but is still substantially faster overall! Splitting the measurements between the building and release of the set shows that releasing multiple buffers immediately after each other improves performance quite a lot.

Answer (score 9):

Using custom allocator with `std::set` can be helpful. If you know the number of elements before constructing the set, you can allocate a raw memory buffer with appropriate size and then override `allocate` method in your custom allocator class(using `std::allocator` as a base class) so that it returns a pointer to an address in the buffer instead of calling `new` operator. It still requires memory allocation, but only once. It might look like that:

```
template<class T, size_t S>
class MyAlloc: public allocator<T>
{
    T *buf;
    size_t ptr;
public:
    MyAlloc()
    {
        buf = (T*)malloc(sizeof(T) * S);
        ptr = 0;
    }

    ~MyAlloc()
    {
        free(buf);
    }

    T* allocate(size_t n, allocator<void>::const_pointer hint=0)
    {
        ptr += n;
        return &buf[ptr - n];
    }

    void deallocate(T* p, size_t n)
    {
        //Do nothing.
    }

    template<class T1>
    struct rebind
    {
        typedef MyAlloc<T1, S> other;
    };
};
```

Comment: While the idea of a custom allocator is good, this implementation is not, it's far too simple. It can only allocate a compile-time-fixed number of elements. Moreover, there is no safeguard against allocating more than that, when `allocate()` returns an invalid pointer.

Comment: I know. It's more like a sketch than ready-to-use implementation.