# no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘std::vector’ and ‘std::vector::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’)

Tags: c++, vector, c++17

I can't find a way to apply the size( ) function.

I have the following output:

```
main.cpp:13:23: error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘std::vector’ and ‘std::vector::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’)
         sort(arr, arr + arr.size());
```

in the following code :

```
vector<int> removeDuplicates2(vector<int> arr)
{
    if(arr.size() == 0) 
    {
        return {};
    } else 
    {
       sort(arr, arr + arr.size());
    }
    vector<int> noDuplicatesArr; 
    noDuplicatesArr.push_back(arr[0]);
    for(int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] != arr[i-1])
        noDuplicatesArr.push_back(arr[i]);
    }
return noDuplicatesArr;
}
```

all code comes from geeksforgeeks.org and edcuba.com documentation so I do not know where to find a solution next;
I've tried to set a new value n

```
vector<int> n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
OR
<int> n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
```

and I get

```
main.cpp:6:33: error: conversion from ‘long unsigned int’ to non-scalar type ‘std::vector’ requested
     vector<int> n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
OR
main.cpp:13:23: error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘std::vector’ and ‘int’)
         sort(arr, arr + n);
```

Comment: What do you expect this to do? `arr + arr.size()`

Comment: You are trying to apply C-style arrays conventions to C++ `std::vector`. That will not work. We can correct each of the mistakes, but I suggest you get [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn from. Geeksforgeeks is notoriously bad source.

Comment: You most likely meant `sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());` And the code that follows is a reimplementation of `std::unique_copy`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That works. I know that already. but i was following some tutorials from geeksforgeeks and I just go stuck

Comment: You may be confusing `std::vector` with C arrays. C arrays easily decay to pointers so it is possible to perform arithmetic operations on them. In that case, the array turns into a pointer to its first element and the arithmetic operation is applied to that pointers, which makes sense. `std::vector` is not an array and does not turn into a pointer. You can use the `data()` to *get* a pointer to the first element, but in C++ the recommended way to interact with containers is iterators. You should use `std::begin(arr)` and `std::end(arr)` instead of `arr` and `arr + arr.size()`.

Comment: `std::begin(arr)` is good to know about, but is more useful in the context of writing a generic function that can't assume the existence of member `begin`, right?

Comment: @NathanPierson it also helps to be consistent. It works the same for containers and c-arrays. If the code OP used as blueprint had used `std::begin` and `std::end` they could have replaced the c-array with a vector with much less friction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some cases it could be faster to use a std::set for deduplicating. That would reduce the data moved, because duplicates never get inserted into the temporary data structure. Then, removeDuplicates2 should get a const reference to eleminate an unnecessary copy of the entire array. Ideally, you could return the constructed set instead of a new vector. In case removeDuplicates2 ever would have to handle different data types, it should be turned into a template.

The resulting function is quite simple:

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> removeDuplicates2(const std::vector<T>& arr)
{
    if(arr.size() == 0) 
    {
        return {};
    }

    // Use a set to remove the duplicates
    std::set<int> set(arr.begin(), arr.end());

    // Copy result back to different container
    std::vector<int> result(set.begin(), set.end());

    return result;
}
```

We could even abstract from the fact a vector is turned in by passing iterators instead. If it turns out the set-based approach is slowed by the allocation strategy, try a custom allocator: [Alternative for std::set without memory reallocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096466/alternative-for-stdset-without-memory-reallocation)

Comment: What's ultimately faster will depend on how many duplicates are in the data to be sorted. As always, users should benchmark several solutions using their own data.

Comment: I wrote that the set "should be faster" than the vector because the set does not need to keep track of the duplicates. If it turns out that in practice the vector-based approach is faster than the set-based approach, because the vector has a smarter allocation strategy, it may help to use the set with a custom allocator, as described here: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096466/alternative-for-stdset-without-memory-reallocation

Answer (score 3):

`sort` takes a pair of iterators as its arguments.

If `arr` was, as the name suggests, a C-style array, then after array-to-pointer decay `arr` and `arr + N` (where `N` is the number of elements in the array) would be pointers to the beginning and the past-the-ending of the array. A pointer is an iterator, so that would be a valid pair of arguments to pass to `sort`.

However, `arr` is not a C-style array, it is a `std::vector<int>`. So `arr` is not an iterator, and `arr + arr.size()` is attempting to add a size to a container and that's just not something that has any meaning. Thankfully, `std::vector` does have member functions for its iterators: [begin](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin) and [end](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end). So instead you can write

```
std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
```